# Is the Kleene star of an intersection always equal to the intersection of kleene stars?

Tags: formal-languages, kleene-star

I know that the  Kleene star of an intersection is contained in the intersection of Kleene stars, but are they necessarily equal?

For example, given two formal languages, $A$ and $B$, I know that $(A\cap B)^*\subseteq A^*\cap B^*$, but does $(A\cap B)^*= A^*\cap B^*$?

Comment: I know it is contained but is it equal =?

Answer (score 4):

Clearly not.

Let $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{aa\}$.

Now,

$A\cap B =  \emptyset$

so

$(A\cap B)^* = \{\epsilon\}$

but

$A^*\cap B^*=B^*=\{a^{2i} : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$

(all strings consisting of an even number of $a$).

Comment: @ttnick: Sorry, I should have gone for "accept and improve". Thanks for bringing this to my attention.